# Is ViewState totally incompatible with Fragment OutputCache?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, outputcache

I have a custom control in a page which uses full and partial output caching. If I simply refresh the page, the control is loaded from cache (I've added a timestamp to verify that). But if I do an action in the control that causes PostBack, the second time I do it the ViewState "loses" a value that was added in Page_Load when `!IsPostBack`. I wonder if there is some way to have both ViewState and OutputCache working in this way.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : MyBaseUserControl
{
    private string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)ViewState["_myProperty"]; }
        set { ViewState["_myProperty"] = value; }
    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);
        var prop = this.MyProperty;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            var value = this.MyProperty; // sometimes gets null
        }
        else
        {
            this.MyProperty = GetNewValue(); // never returns empty or null
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** After posting the question, SO showed other related questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770366/viewstate-of-ascx-lost-between-postbacks)), so I've reviewed Page Life Cycle and overriden `LoadViewState` method, and set breakpoints. When page (and control) is first loaded, `Page_Load` is called, but `LoadViewState` not; in first PostBack, `LoadViewState` is called and `MyProperty` has the correct content; in second PostBack, again `Page_Load` is called, but `LoadViewState` not, and `MyProperty` has `null` value.

**Edit 2:** I've debugged a little more (by comparing execution with Output Cache disabled) and found out that control postbacks (an `asp:GridView`'s `OnSelectedIndexChanging` event) force the page to refresh by injecting a `window.location=window.location;` JavaScript in the page. But with cache enabled, gridview's event is executed only in the first postback, but not in the second one, preventing the page (and, subsequently, the control) to be reloaded to complete its task. But it's not the only problem, because of the property stored in ViewState.